# How can I remove the background behind the JtabbedPane, or change its colour

Tags: java, jtabbedpane

[image]

Hi, I have a JTabbedPane as above. I want to remove, or change the colour of the background, behind the tab "Select Tab." I've been searching for a long time and cannot find any info on it

Answer (score 0):

Behind the tab means.. outer container. Use setBackground(Color) method on outer container.
See below code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TabbedPaneTabColor extends JPanel {
    public TabbedPaneTabColor() {
        initializeUI();
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));


        JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);// This line sets the JPANEL(container) color to black

        pane.addTab("A Tab", new JPanel());
        pane.addTab("B Tab", new JPanel());
        pane.addTab("C Tab", new JPanel());
        pane.addTab("D Tab", new JPanel());


        pane.setForeground(Color.BLACK);


        pane.setBackgroundAt(0, Color.RED);
        pane.setBackgroundAt(1, Color.GREEN);
        pane.setBackgroundAt(2, Color.YELLOW);
        pane.setBackgroundAt(3, Color.ORANGE);

        this.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void showFrame() {
        JPanel panel = new TabbedPaneTabColor();
        panel.setOpaque(true);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTabbedPane Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                TabbedPaneTabColor.showFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```